# check N/A value in mysql database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, null, phpmyadmin, conditional-statements

My database record contains column which is N/A value which is null.

But when I retrieve them from mysql database. It shows me N/A value which I don't want to see.
I did a check for that ,but no luck, the checking condition is fail

I used

```
empty()
is_null()
$my_variable == null
$my_variable == " "
```

but the check still fail.
Any know how to use PHP to check the value that retrieved from the database?

updated ques:
    Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Actio

```
 4  description text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
```

default is none

Comment: is it text "N/A" "NULL" or an actual NULL?

Comment: it is NUll, but database display it as N/A

Comment: What is the table schema? Is the field setup with NULL set to YES and a default of 'N/A' or NULL? e.g `field1 varchar(25) NOT NULL default 'N/A', field2 varchar(25) default NULL`

Comment: erm, it is setup like this  description text latin1_swedish_ci  No None

Comment: So it cannot store NULL and the default is '' - empty string

Answer (score 1):

I changed it to default NULL and the field can be NULL, then right now I can check for null value.